# How to merge the values on the basis of one column in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union

I am running this query and getting the data like attached below

```
mysql> ( SELECT date_range AS 'Time Elapsed', COUNT(*) AS 'Conversions' FROM `data` GROUP BY date_sort_sno, `date_range` ORDER BY date_sort_sno )
    ->     UNION ALL
    -> ( SELECT date_range AS 'Time Elapsed', COUNT(*) AS 'A_Conversio' FROM `data` GROUP BY date_sort_sno, `date_range` WHERE name = 'Alpha' ORDER BY date_sort_sno );
```

OUTPUT

```
+------------------------------+-------------+
| Time Elapsed                 | Conversions |
+------------------------------+-------------+
| Less than equal to 5 minutes |        1391 |
| 5 to 30 minutes              |        9108 |
| 30 to 60 minutes             |        2233 |
| 1 hour to 3 hours            |        2280 |
| 3 hours to 24 hours          |        4585 |
| 1 to 3 days                  |        4143 |
| 3 to 6 days                  |         155 |
| more than 6 days             |          80 |
| Less than equal to 5 minutes |        1391 |
| 5 to 30 minutes              |        9108 |
| 30 to 60 minutes             |        2233 |
| 1 hour to 3 hours            |        2280 |
| 3 hours to 24 hours          |        4585 |
| 1 to 3 days                  |        4143 |
| 3 to 6 days                  |         155 |
| more than 6 days             |          80 |
+------------------------------+-------------+
```

Problem Statement:
I want to merge the data on the basis of Time Elapsed like

```
+------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
| Time Elapsed                 | Conversions | A_Conversio |
+------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
| Less than equal to 5 minutes |        1391 |        1231 |
| 5 to 30 minutes              |        1391 |        4455 |
| 30 to 60 minutes             |        2233 |        3333 |
| 1 hour to 3 hours            |        2280 |        4343 |
| 3 hours to 24 hours          |        4585 |        2234 |
| 1 to 3 days                  |        4143 |        2344 |
| 3 to 6 days                  |         155 |         455 |
| more than 6 days             |          80 |          11 |
+------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of two separate queries, you could have one query with two columns - a plain old `count(*)` to count all the records and a `count` function applied to a `case` expression to count only the conversions where the name is `'Alpha'`:

```
SELECT   date_range AS 'Time Elapsed', 
         COUNT(*) AS 'Conversions',
         COUNT(CASE name WHEN 'Alpha' THEN 1 END) AS 'A_Conversio'
FROM     `data`
GROUP BY date_sort_sno, `date_range`
ORDER BY date_sort_sno
```

Comment: A_Conversio needs an end quote. I'm unable to edit for a single character.

Comment: @Jtbs indeed, thanks for noticing! Edited and fixed.